# Is there a way to detect if a user has animations disabled on their OS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a frontend application using React, and am rendering an animation on one of the components. If the user has animations disabled in their settings, I'd like to display a static image in its place. Is there a way to tell if animations have been disabled so I can do some conditional rendering?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion

Comment: wow this appears to be exactly what I need, thank you!! my google search wasn't turning up any useful results.

Answer (score 5):

@Phix gives [the relevant standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion).

To check in JavaScript as requested, you can use

```js
const query = window.matchMedia(
  '(prefers-reduced-motion: reduce)');
if(query.matches) ... else ...
```

In React, you could use [@react-hook/media-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-hook/media-query) as follows:

```js
import {useMediaQuery} from '@react-hook/media-query'

const Component = () => {
  const matches = useMediaQuery(
    '(prefers-reduced-motion: reduce)');
  return matches ? ... : ...;
}
```